# Need to find correct 28 triples

Tags: java

Hi guys I found interesting question from InterviewSteet site.. I'm little bit confused with question. Help me with understanding question please. I'm getting 35 triples but only 28 is expected from sample. I added my 35triples output. please help me to find 28 triples.
wat is my mistake in understanding question. i

Question:

> There is an integer array d which does not contain more than two
>   elements of the same value. How many distinct ascending triples (d[i]
>   < d[j] < d[k], i < j < k) are present?

Input format

> The first line contains an integer N denoting the number of elements
>   in the array. This is followed by a single line containing N integers
>   separated by a single space with no leading/trailing spaces

Output format:

> A single integer that denotes the number of distinct ascending triples
>   present in the array

Constraints:

```
N <= 10^5
Every element of the array is present at most twice
Every element of the array is a 32-bit positive integer
```

Sample input:

```
6
1 1 2 2 3 4
```

Sample output:

```
 4
```

Explanation:
The distinct triplets are

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,4)
(2,3,4)
```

my input:

```
10
1 1 5 4 3 6 6 5 9 10
```

my output:

```
35
```

Explanation:
The distinct triplets are

```
(1,3,4)
```

(1,3,5)
(1,3,6)
(1,3,9)
(1,3,10)
(1,4,5)
(1,4,6)
(1,4,9)
(1,4,10)
(1,5,6)
(1,5,9)
(1,5,10)
(1,6,9)
(1,6,10)
(1,9,10)
(3,4,5)
(3,4,6)
(3,4,9)
(3,4,10)
(3,5,6)
(3,5,9)
(3,5,10)
(3,6,9)
(3,6,10)
(3,9,10)
(4,5,6)
(4,5,9)
(4,5,10)
(4,6,9)
(4,6,10)
(4,9,10)
(5,6,9)
(5,6,10)
(5,9,10)
(6,9,10)

Expected output:

```
28
```

I'm getting `35 triples` but `28` is correct answer. wat is my mistake??

Comment: In your list, (5, 4, 3) is obviously not correct for example. And a few others. And you are missing a few, like (1, 3, 5) for example. As to *"wat is my mistake??"* I can only say that your algorithm (which you have not shown) is wrong...

Comment: (1,5,4) (1,5,3) are definitely not ascending triples

Comment: (1,5,4)
(1,5,3)
(5,4,3) (5,4,6) (5,4,9) (5,4,10) (5,3,6) (5,3,9) (5,3,10) (4,3,6) (4,3,9) wrong triples. check your logic.

Comment: oops thanks for your reply assylias.. I changed and ordered triples order. so now i got 35 unique ascending ordered triples.. still i'm getting 35 :(
(1,3,4)
(1,3,5)
(1,3,6)
(1,3,9)
(1,3,10)
(1,4,5)
(1,4,6)
(1,4,9)
(1,4,10)
(1,5,6)
(1,5,9)
(1,5,10)
(1,6,9)
(1,6,10)
(1,9,10)
(3,4,5)
(3,4,6)
(3,4,9)
(3,4,10)
(3,5,6)
(3,5,9)
(3,5,10)
(3,6,9)
(3,6,10)
(3,9,10)
(4,5,6)
(4,5,9)
(4,5,10)
(4,6,9)
(4,6,10)
(4,9,10)
(5,6,9)
(5,6,10)
(5,9,10)
(6,9,10)

Comment: thanks roryB and azodious. now can u please check frm comment and try it..

Comment: 1, 3, 4 is not possible, because the only 4 in the list comes before the 3. Remember that not only does d[i] < d[j] < d[k] hold true, but so does i < j < k.

Comment: hi Lincoded, question only states the d[i] < d[j] < d[k], i < j < k for this (1, 3, 4) is right only!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you  are calculating the total possible combination by n! / (n-3)!3!.
But you will have to remove all those triplet which are not in ascending order.